# find the ratio of the frequency of a given letter in the word to the length of the word

Tags: python

Write a Python application to input any word and find the ratio of the frequency of a given
letter in the word to the length of the word. Provide five different outputs.
(E.g. Input the word: appear
Input a letter to find the frequency: p
Frequency of letter p: Word Length = 2:3)

To answer to my question

Comment: Surely `p` appears twice out of ***six*** letters? Not three? (2:6 or 1:3, but not 2:3)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.